# Flash FaceBook Integration

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook

I have checked some documentions about the Facebook api that communicates with flash and its easy to login / out, send messages and stuff, the problem is that only works with air and flex.

The thing is that i want to make a crude flash application to log in and send messages. Anyone has anyidea of how to do it? Because the api doesnt work on crude flash.

I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought the same thing but this isn't true. There is actually an example in the SDK that works out of the box under "FacebookAPI\examples\FlashWebExample\FlashWebExample.fla."

Works just fine. :)

Also here it is in SVN:

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fexamples%2FFlashWebExample

Comment: I tried to run it, oppened the .fla file and it did nothing with the Login button. Any ideas?

Comment: After it calls the: Facebook.login(onLogin, opts); Nothing happens!

Comment: You've gotta configure your facebook app settings, specifically the canvas settings (where the location of the app is). Upload your SWF + the HTML file to your server and tell facebook to point to that address to load the HTML page. Should work fine. Testing locally doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Perhaps I should say, testing a facebook web app doesn't seem to work when testing locally. AIR based works fine.